# The ideal $(xy + 1, x^6 + 5x^3 + 1)$ is not principal

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ideals

In my algebra class, I have been asked to show that the ideal generated by $xy + 1, x^6 + 5x^3 + 1 \in Z_{7}[x,y]$, denoted by $I$, is not a principal ideal.

It's fairly easy to see that if the ideal was principal, then it must had been $(1)=I=Z_{7}[x,y]$.
I continued by showing there are no polynomials $u(x,y), v(x,y) \in Z_{7}[x,y]$, such that:
$u(x,y)(xy+1) + v(x,y)(x^6+5x^3 +1) = 1$. This part ended up to be quite convoluted.

Is there a simpler way to prove this claim?

## Edit

I think I figured it out. By the second isomorphism theorem:
$$
I/(xy+1)  \simeq  (x^6+5x^3+1)/((x^6+5x^3+1)\cap (xy+1))
$$

If we assume $I$ is a principal domain, then we can easly show $I = Z_{7}[x,y]$.
 And by the fact that $xy+1$ is irreducible in $Z_{7}[x,y]$, we also have $(x^6+5x^3+1)\cap (xy+1) = ((x^6+5x^3+1)(xy+1))$.
Therefore:
$$
Z_{7}[x,y]/(xy+1) \simeq (x^6+5x^3+1)/ ((x^6+5x^3+1)(xy+1))
$$

Using once more the fact $xy+1$ is irreducible, then $(xy+1)$ is a maximal ideal and $Z_{7}[x,y]/(xy+1)$ is a field. Now it's only required to show that $(x^6+5x^3+1)/ ((x^6+5x^3+1)(xy+1))$ is not a field. And therefore $I$ is not a principal ideal.

Comment: *HInt:* $xy + 1$ is irreducible in $Z_{7}[y][x]$.

Comment: I noticed that $xy+1$, is irreducible. Indeed if we say that $I$ is generated by m(x,y), then $(xy+1) \subset (m(x,y))$, and therefore m(x,y) divides $xy+1$. Since $xy+1$ is irreducible, and $[Z_{7}[x]][y]$ is a unique factorization domain, we must have that $m(x,y)$ is a unit, or $m(x,y)=xy+1$. It's straightforward that $m(x,y) \neq xy+1$, still leaving the case $m(x,y)=1$.

Comment: I guess you missed that $x^6+5x^3 +1$ has a root in $\mathbb Z_7$.

Comment: A cubic may be more comfortable to work with, so it may be worth observing that
$$x^6+5x^3+1=x^6-2x^3+1=(x^3-1)^2.$$ In case you want to approach this using common zeros, then we can factor further $(x^3-1)=(x-1)(x-2)(x-4)$.

Comment: For example, $I$ cannot be all of $\Bbb{Z}_7[x,y]$ because $f(1,-1)=0$ for all $f(x,y)\in I$.

Answer (score 4):

> *There are no polynomials $u(x,y), v(x,y) \in \mathbb Z_{7}[x,y]$ such that $u(x,y)(xy+1) + v(x,y)(x^6+5x^3 +1) = 1$. This part ended up to be quite convoluted.*

Let us assume there are such polynomials and set $x=1$. We get $u(1,y)(y+1)=1$. Now set $y=-1$.

Comment: I was about post an answer using zeros of the generators. Then I saw your answer. +1 of course.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is another way to prove that $I$ cannot be $\mathbb Z_7[x,y]$.

Consider the quotient :
\begin{align*}
\mathbb Z_7[x,y] / I &\simeq (\mathbb Z_7[x] / (x^6 + 5x^3 + 1))[y] / (xy + 1) \\
& \simeq\mathbb Z_7[x] / (x^6 + 5x^3 + 1) \\
&\not\simeq 0
\end{align*}
where the second line is obtained by noticing that $x$ is invertible in $\mathbb Z_7[x] / (x^6 + 5x^3 + 1)$

We conclude that $I \neq \mathbb Z_7[x,y]$